# Parallelization of groupby function applied to dictionary

Tags: dictionary, group-by, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

A few days ago I've come up with a groupby function applied to dictionaries.

Here it the code :

```
def dict_groupby(d, key):
    """
    Group a dictionary by a specified key.

    Args:
        d (dict): The input dictionary.
        key: The key to group the dictionary by.

    Returns:
        dict: A new dictionary where values are subdictionaries grouped by the specified key.

    Example:
        >>> data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'C': [True, False, True, False]}
        >>> result = dict_groupby(data, 'C')
        >>> print(result)
        {True: {'A': [1, 3], 'B': ['a', 'c']}, False: {'A': [2, 4], 'B': ['b', 'd']}}
    """

    dd = {}
    keys = set(d) - {key}
    for i, k in enumerate(d[key]):
        d2 = dd.setdefault(k, {})
        for k2 in keys:
            d2.setdefault(k2, []).append(d[k2][i])
    return dd
```

I'm trying to optimize it with parallelization, but the imbrication of the 2 loops makes things hard.

Here is my first attempt with the concurrent.futures library (the result isn't correct sadly):

```
def dict_groupby_thread(d, key):
    dd = {}

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for k, sub_dict in zip(d[key], executor.map(lambda i: {k: v[i] for k, v in d.items()},    range(len(d[key])))):
            dd.setdefault(k, {}).update(sub_dict)

    return dd
```

Any ideas to get to the right result?

Thanks,